# Set the file in the raw folder as the media player's data source in android Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

I'm quite new to android development right now, so I need help with some obvious things. I'm trying to make a simple audio player using the built-in compose MediaPlayer jetpack. I can set the resource file when I create it, e.g. R.raw.*filename*, but when I want to change the media source, I can't use that construct in the setMediaSource arguments.

I've tried using uri, but it doesn't work in the end. I'm assuming I'm using uri incorrectly, but I can't find any guidance.

This how I create MediaPlayer
`val mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(LocalContext.current, R.raw.birds)`

And that's how I tried to change the source, and there are no functions that can be called in this way.
`mPlayer.setDataSource(R.raw.city)`

So, how should I change the data source correctly?